# Cannot create new app on the Autodesk Forge website

Tags: autodesk-forge

When I try to create a new forge app (`https://forge.autodesk.com/myapps/create#`) I get the following error in the developer console of chrome:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (app_au.min.orig.js:3)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (vendor.min.orig.js:3)
    at HTMLInputElement.q.handle (vendor.min.orig.js:3)
```

I already have created 2 app for development so it should not be an authorization issue. And the error looks like a client JS bug to me.

Comment: Can you try this from Incognito it might be a caching problem, we don't see the current error at the moment. Also can you check that your subscription is still enabled and you have not ran out of the Trial period.

Comment: We have a basic paid forge account. Incognito did not work for me. Same error message.

Comment: Any solution? Having the same problem

Comment: Unfortunately no. I reused an already existing forge app for now.

Comment: Can you send us an email to forge.help@autodesk.com we will jump in a call with you. Apologies for the continuous problem.

Comment: I just tested it again and it works now.